# Pattern-based substitution in the txt via AWK

Tags: text, awk, sed

I have a long text file where somewhere near the end there is a 1 line, with the 3rd column == OXT.

```
ATOM   2439  O   LEU   300      -4.699  34.599  65.335  1.00 83.23           O
ATOM   2440  N   LEU   301      -6.822  33.898  65.057  1.00 19.70           N
ATOM   2441  CA  LEU   301      -7.080  34.965  64.138  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2442  CB  LEU   301      -8.165  34.630  63.101  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2443  CG  LEU   301      -7.762  33.478  62.162  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2444  CD1 LEU   301      -8.849  33.207  61.110  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2445  CD2 LEU   301      -6.376  33.719  61.543  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2446  C   LEU   301      -7.556  36.168  64.946  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2447  O   LEU   301      -8.657  36.695  64.633  1.00 19.70           O
ATOM   2448  OXT LEU   301      -6.821  36.580  65.884  1.00 19.70           O
TER    2449      LEU   301
HETATM 2450 NA    NA   302     -13.016  13.036  54.214  1.00 44.33          NA
HETATM 2451  O   WAT   303     -18.411  13.587  59.094  1.00 27.41           O
HETATM 2452  O   WAT   304     -11.894  17.279  58.575  1.00 18.35           O
HETATM 2453  O   WAT   305     -15.811  12.728  54.157  1.00 39.81           O
```

I need to modify this line with the pattern OXT (see example below) in a following fashion: in a third column - substitute "OXT" with "N  "; in a forth column - substitute ACE with NHE; in a last column substitute O with N. Importantly after the substitutions I need to keep the equal space numbers between each of the columns as in the rest of the file:

```
ATOM   2439  O   LEU   300      -4.699  34.599  65.335  1.00 83.23           O
ATOM   2440  N   LEU   301      -6.822  33.898  65.057  1.00 19.70           N
ATOM   2441  CA  LEU   301      -7.080  34.965  64.138  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2442  CB  LEU   301      -8.165  34.630  63.101  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2443  CG  LEU   301      -7.762  33.478  62.162  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2444  CD1 LEU   301      -8.849  33.207  61.110  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2445  CD2 LEU   301      -6.376  33.719  61.543  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2446  C   LEU   301      -7.556  36.168  64.946  1.00 19.70           C
ATOM   2447  O   LEU   301      -8.657  36.695  64.633  1.00 19.70           O
ATOM   2448  N   NHE   301      -6.821  36.580  65.884  1.00 19.70           N
TER
HETATM 2450 NA    NA   302     -13.016  13.036  54.214  1.00 44.33          NA
HETATM 2451  O   WAT   303     -18.411  13.587  59.094  1.00 27.41           O
HETATM 2452  O   WAT   304     -11.894  17.279  58.575  1.00 18.35           O
HETATM 2453  O   WAT   305     -15.811  12.728  54.157  1.00 39.81           O
```

I have tried to use

```
awk '$3=="OXT"{ f=1; rn=NR; $3=$NF="N"; $4="NHE" }/TER/ && f && NR-rn == 1{ $0=$1 }1' file
```

It has produced a right job but within a new string now I have 1 space between each columns which is wrong format.

```
ATOM 2410 N NHE 299 -17.563 -15.711 -15.915 1.00 76.42 N
```

However I need to keep the original format of the spacings between the columns as in the rest of the file:

```
ATOM   2448  N   NHE   301      -6.821  36.580  65.884  1.00 19.70           N
```

Comment: the same duplicate story https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487293/substitution-of-the-columns-found-in-pattern-via-bash

Comment: it produce correct thing in the substitution strings but destroy some parts of the rest file: shifting the last two columns thus producing artefacts.

Comment: @m47730 Concerning Edit: There's no reason this problem could not be solved with a different shell. Limiting answers to only `bash` would be unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: the script in a below comment written in bash works very well !!! it's a combination of bash and sed !

Answer (score 1):

quick and very dirty:

```
#/bin/bash

skip=0
cat /tmp/list | while read line
do
  third=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')

  if [ $skip -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo "TER"
    skip=0
    continue
  fi

  if [ "${third}" == "OXT" ]
  then
    echo "${line}" | sed 's/OXT/N  /'
    skip=1
    continue
  fi

  echo "${line}"
done
```

of course the */tmp/list* is the file with all values.

Comment: Thanks! Generally it works fine. But how to add to sed an additional scripts to substitute also values in 4th (any tree capital letters on NHE) and the last columns (substitute O to N). Something like for 4th column (which unfortunately also substitute the 1st column of the same string which is bad):  sed -e 's/OXT/N  /'  -e 's/[[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:upper:]]/NHE/g'

Comment: @JamesStarlight update your question with this new issues; put on also this time the input and the expected output.
In this description way i don't really sure to catch your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the result of your command to the `column` command:

```
$>awk  '$3=="OXT"{ f=1; rn=NR; $3=$NF="N"; $4="NHE" }/TER/ && f && NR-rn == 1{ $0=$1 }1' f|column -t
ATOM    2439  O    LEU  300  -4.699   34.599  65.335  1.00  83.23  O
ATOM    2440  N    LEU  301  -6.822   33.898  65.057  1.00  19.70  N
ATOM    2441  CA   LEU  301  -7.080   34.965  64.138  1.00  19.70  C
ATOM    2442  CB   LEU  301  -8.165   34.630  63.101  1.00  19.70  C
ATOM    2443  CG   LEU  301  -7.762   33.478  62.162  1.00  19.70  C
ATOM    2444  CD1  LEU  301  -8.849   33.207  61.110  1.00  19.70  C
ATOM    2445  CD2  LEU  301  -6.376   33.719  61.543  1.00  19.70  C
ATOM    2446  C    LEU  301  -7.556   36.168  64.946  1.00  19.70  C
ATOM    2447  O    LEU  301  -8.657   36.695  64.633  1.00  19.70  O
ATOM    2448  N    NHE  301  -6.821   36.580  65.884  1.00  19.70  N
TER
HETATM  2450  NA   NA   302  -13.016  13.036  54.214  1.00  44.33  NA
HETATM  2451  O    WAT  303  -18.411  13.587  59.094  1.00  27.41  O
HETATM  2452  O    WAT  304  -11.894  17.279  58.575  1.00  18.35  O
HETATM  2453  O    WAT  305  -15.811  12.728  54.157  1.00  39.81  O
```

Comment: it produces correct output in the substitution strings but destroy some parts of the rest of the original file, In some parts the the last two columns were shifted and even merged together,  thus producing wrong output files.

Comment: maybe coupling with `fmt` or using the `-c` option?

Comment: like this it does not work    awk '$3=="OXT"{ f=1; rn=NR; $3=$NF="N"; $4="NHE" }/TER/ && f && NR-rn == 1{ $0=$1 }1' file | column -t | fmt